# whay dont work react router after run build?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

why react router dont work after build?!
It works in my local but it does not work after uploading

App.js

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import {  Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

      const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

      const store = createStore(
          rootReducer,
          applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware,loggerMiddleware));

    return (
              <Provider store={store}>

                                <Switch>

                                    <Route   path="/login" component={Login} key="Login"></Route>
                                    <Route  exact path="/" component={Home} key="Home"></Route>
                                    <Route   path="/register" component={Register} key="Register"></Route>
                                    <Route   path="/dashboard" render={props => <RTLLayout {...props} />}/>
                                    <Route   path="/edit" component={Editor} key="Editor"></Route>
                                    
                                </Switch>
                    </Provider>
```

index.js

```````
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode >
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

``````
```````

Comment: what error do you see in console when you run it after build?

Answer (score 1):

If it works in local it can be because of your hosting. Github pages for example does not support react-router, you should try hash router in this case.
Add please your full app.js file content to see if there are errors.